# Performance Implication of a static List <> with Itmes that Takes Long to Create

Tags: c#, performance, static

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC5 project which has a big `static List<Item>` looking like the following:

```
public static class Items {
    private static List<Item> items = new List<Item> {
        new Item(),
        new Item(),
        //... add many items
        new Item()
    };
    public static List<Item> ToList() {
        return items;
    }
}
public class Item {
    public Item() {
        // Some Tasks that takes a while
    }
}
```

`Items.ToList()` is called in many places in the app. Since `Items` is static, I assume the resulting object lives in the memory, and `Item` ojects are created only once - but I couldn't find a good enough low-level explanation to understand how exactly this would work.

I wanted to understand the following:

1. When does this `Items.items` get created?
2. Is there a performance issue doing things like this?
3. If 2. is true, what would be a better way to create such static object?

Comment: Your design seems really weird to me, what is the need for a static class anyway?  What does your Item constructor actually do?

Comment: @maccettura, the Item constructor uses reflection to set one of its properties to a WSDL generated Enum based on a string parameter (not included in the example above)
In my app, I was using it to populate a list of US States, with associated enum from the external service reference. 
Am I on a wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the initial instantiation of the list is taking a while, since the constructor of each object is not trivial. You could run this in parallel - inside a static constructor

```
static Items()
{
    items = Enumerable.Repeat(new Item(), Count).AsParallel().ToList();
}
```

but in this case, the final order inside the list is not defined.

Comment: It is dangerous to do anything involving multiple threads in a static initializer. Do you understand why?

Comment: Right
https://ericlippert.com/2013/01/31/the-no-lock-deadlock/ ;)

I don't refer the Items type within the concurrent part, but if I would, say the Item type be a nested class - this would be a really nasty deadlock.

Comment: Indeed! But it doesn't have to be a nested type. Suppose `new Item()`  does *anything* that causes *any* code to touch `Items`.  The result could be a deadlock.

Comment: Also, remember that since `Items` does not have an explicit static constructor, the .NET runtime is free to call its static initializers *when a method that refers to `Items` is jitted*, rather than upon the first usage of `Items`.  If `new Item()` contains `if (false) Items.Whatever();` then that will still count as a usage of `Items` from the perspective of the CLR, even though the usage is not reachable.

Comment: Yeah, I used the nested type just as an example of something that refers to the type which is being initialized